# How can I alter this code to accept a slug as well as an ID?

Tags: php, functions

This code is from the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category).

```
/* ==  If In Parent Category... ==============================*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use it in the theme like this:

`if ( post_is_in_descendant_category( 11 ) ) ...`

It only accepts the post ID (`11`), however, and I'd like it to accept the slug. Is there a way to alter this code somehow to accept the slug?

Comment: @Brad I edited the question to make it more clear. Basically, when I use the function in the theme, I want to be able to use the slug of the category rather than the ID (in this case, `11`). I'm not much of a coder so I'm not exactly sure how to start changing what.

Comment: [`in_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) accepts a slug, so the show-stopper at the moment is probably that you are casting `$cat` as an integer when getting the term children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Codex essentially explains how to do this:

> ```
> if ( $category_to_check = get_term_by( 'name', 'fruit', 'category' ))
>    post_is_in_descendant_category($category_to_check->term_id);
> ```
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category#Testing_if_a_post_is_in_a_descendant_category

Putting it all together in your function you would have:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_is_in_descendant_category' ) ) {
    function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
        foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
            if (!absint($cat)) {
//            $cat = get_category_by_slug($cat); // option one
              $cat = get_term_by('slug',$cat,'category'); // option two
//            $cat = get_term_by('name',$cat,'category'); // option three; by category name, not slug, as in the Codex
              if(!$cat) return false;
              $cat = $cat->term_id;
            }
            // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
            $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
            if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```